# How to change drawer header height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I am wanting to change the header height of the drawer, as my intention for the drawer to be a settings page. But at the moment it is to thick. How would I do this. This is my sample code so far:

```
return Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: <Widget>[
      DrawerHeader(
        child: Text('Settings'),
      ),
    ]
  )
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can Wrap Your Widget with Container.

```
Container(
   height: 50.0,
   child: DrawerHeader(
      child: Text('Setting'),
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return new Container(
  height : 100.0    // your specified height
  child: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: <Widget>[
      DrawerHeader(
        child: Text('Settings'),
      ),
    ]
  )
);
```

Comment: You might want to explain what this code does and how it solves the problem. Code only answers are rarely helpful to future visitors.